Backtracking line search in gradient descent for a function with inputs of multiple dimensions
I am trying to use gradient descent to minimize a function that takes in multiple vectors, so something like $\min f(x_1, x_2,.., x_N)$ where each $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^3$.
and the output is a scalar.
I'm storing the input in a 3xN matrix, and creating a matrix for the gradients of the same size where each column corresponds to $g_j =\nabla_j f$, the gradient corresponding to input $x_j$.
And the iterates are formed as $x_j^{(k+1)} = x_j^{(k)} + \alpha^{(k)}\cdot p_j^{(k)}$, where $p_j = -g_j$.
Now, my question is about using backtracking to find a good step size.
I know that, in general, we want to to choose $\alpha_k$ to satisfy $g(x^{(k+1)}) < g(x^{(k)}) + c\alpha_k\cdot \nabla g(x^{(k)})^Tp_k$, where $c\in (0,1]$.
I am confused as to how to apply this to a function that takes in multiple inputs in multiple dimensions. Would I have to choose a different $\alpha^{(k)}$ for each input vector so that the update step should actually be
$$ x_j^{(k+1)} = x_j^{(k)} + \alpha_j^{(k)}\cdot p_j^{(k)}$$
for all $j=1,...,N$?
And then use backtracking to find, for example $\alpha_1^{(k)}$,  to satisfy $$f(x_1^{(k)}+ \alpha_1^{(k)}p_1^{(k)}, ..., x_N^{(k)})  < f(x_1^{(k)}, ..., x_N^{(k)}) + c\cdot \alpha_1^{(k)}g_1^{(k)^T}p_1^{(k)}$$, and do this to find the step size for all input vectors?

For the purpose of taking a gradient, think about $f$ as a function with one input - a vector of length $3N$ that is a "flattened stack" of the $x_i$.
Now you have one gradient vector, one step size, and one step size criterion (instead of $N$). Then you'll effectively be able update all the $x_i$ at once.
